# PHP looping through csv file and returning incorrect row

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

Simply trying to use the url query string as a lookup code in an csv table. This works 9/10 times, but on occasion this will return the wrong line (usually a few lines below what should be the correct line).

csv looks something like this

```
taskcode1, info1, info1, info1

taskcode2, info2, info2, info2

taskcode3, info3, info3, info3
```

The problem is that sometimes (around 1/10 times so far), a given url query of taskcode1 will actually return line info3.

This csv file is being read concurrently by more than one user. Could the problem be stemming from simultaneously reading? I know there can be issues for writing, and a flock on the file may be necessary. Here's the actual code in my php script. Thank you for any advice.

Notice that as soon as the task code is found, $this_taskcode == $taskcode, I break the while loop.

```
//get query from request and look up task configuration
$csv_file_path = "tasks.csv";
$taskcode = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];

//open csv file and find taskcode
$fid = fopen($csv_file_path, 'r');

//loop through each line of csv until taskcode is found, then save the whole line as $hit
while (($line = fgetcsv($fid)) !== FALSE){

    $this_taskcode = $line[0];

    if ($this_taskcode == $taskcode){
        $hit = $line;
        break;
    };
}

fclose($fid);
```

Comment: If two users are reading the same file, always lock it.

Comment: If the result is the last line in some cases, can't it be that the `$taskcode` wasn't found and you use `$line` somewhere below that piece of code?

Comment: @Stefan, Good suggestion. If the desired line is the very last row in the csv, it still works just fine (just checked). Plus, the problem has occurred higher up in the csv, not just the last line. Thanks!

Comment: @estshy File locking isn't necessary unless the content of the file is expected to be changed as it's being read. Two processes reading from the same file without changing it cause no concurrency issues. See [Race conditions definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) for more information on when locks are appropriate.